# depth_image_proc xyzrgb

Tags: ros, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a point cloud using depth_image_proc xyzrgb. Everything seems ok but it does not publish the cloud.
If some one has time to look at this I would appreciate it very much. Hopefully it is simple. I have attached a bag file which reproduces the issue it is 183 MB. Thank you for your time. I've looked at this with rqt_bag and it looks fine to me. I do not believe the callback is being called for the Synch.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/70av8talgn5rcak/2016-02-14-12-43-12.bag?dl=0

```
<launch>
      <group ns="camera">
        <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet"  args="manager"/>
        <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="depth_image_proc" args="load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb standalone_nodelet" output="screen">
        </node>
      </group>
    </launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226712/depth_image_proc-xyzrgb/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2016-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bag file messages out of order message: I assume this is the cause of my current issue.

```
1456765838.141712524 WARN [/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:187(sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::checkInterMessageBound) [topics: /rosout, /camera/depth_registered/points, /camera/standalone_nodelet/bond] Messages of type 2 arrived out of order (will print only once)
```

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oh233](https://answers.ros.org/users/30294/oh233/) on 2018-01-23**:
Hi munziata. Did you finally solve this problem?